# How do I print a list in an SVG element in react?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, svg, frontend

I am trying to print a list inside of a rectangular element in React. Currently, the list is printing   correctly (so I know am formatting everything correctly in regards to including li tags around the items, etc.) above the rectangle, and the rectangle prints below it. The text "Title Here" prints correctly inside the box. The problem is that the list must be represented by a state, and is of unknown size. How do I print this list inside the rectangle?

```
<div>
        <ul>{this.state.ListText}</ul>
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 610 150" version="1.1">
                <defs>
                    <linearGradient x1="51.7971499%" y1="47.5635228%" x2="52.4921324%" y2="48.1654036%" id="linearGradient-1">
                        <stop stopColor="#9198A1" offset="0%"></stop>
                        <stop stopColor="#888D95" offset="100%"></stop>
                    </linearGradient>
                    <rect id="path-2" x="0" y="0" width="610" height="150" rx="7.2"></rect>
                </defs>
                <g id="Patient-Page" stroke="none" strokeWidth="1" fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
                    <g id="Desktop-HD" transform="translate(-732.000000, -106.000000)">
                        <g id="Medications" transform="translate(732.000000, 106.000000)">
                            <g id="Rectangle-7">
                                <use fillOpacity="0.55" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)" fillRule="evenodd" xlinkHref="#path-2"></use>
                            </g>
                            <text fontFamily="Helvetica" fontSize="32" fontWeight="normal" fill="#000000">
                                <tspan x="165" y="39">Title Here</tspan>
                            </text>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) to embed HTML in your SVG.

You can use jQuery to manipulate the `foreignObject` DOM properties and to append HTML such as your list.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>{this.state.ListText}</ul>
  <span id='cont'>
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 610 150" version="1.1">
                <defs>
                    <linearGradient x1="51.7971499%" y1="47.5635228%" x2="52.4921324%" y2="48.1654036%" id="linearGradient-1">
                        <stop stopColor="#9198A1" offset="0%"></stop>
                        <stop stopColor="#888D95" offset="100%"></stop>
                    </linearGradient>
                    <rect id="path-2" x="0" y="0" width="610" height="150" rx="7.2"></rect>
                </defs>
                <g id="Patient-Page" stroke="none" strokeWidth="1" fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
                    <g id="Desktop-HD" transform="translate(-732.000000, -106.000000)">
                        <g id="Medications" transform="translate(732.000000, 106.000000)">
                            <g id="Rectangle-7">
                                <use fillOpacity="0.55" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)" fillRule="evenodd" xlinkHref="#path-2"></use>
                            </g>
                            <text fontFamily="Helvetica" fontSize="32" fontWeight="normal" fill="#000000" >
                                <tspan x="165" y="39">Title Here</tspan>
                    
    
                            </text>
                       <foreignObject width="100" height="300"
                   requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                           <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                               <p>Here is my list</p>
                           </body>
                       </foreignObject>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </svg>
            </span>
</div>
<script>
  var ul = $('<ul>');
  ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"].forEach(function(item) {
    ul.append($("<li>").text(item));

  });
  $('foreignObject').append(ul);
  $('foreignObject body').append(ul);
</script>
```